Make a regular expression considering the conditions
I'm very bad at regular expressions and don't really understand them. But I want to make my code work great! I have a task to get all the DOI from a large text, but immediately there are problems, namely the difference in the display of the DOI.
DOI: 10.1...
DOI:10.1...
http(s)://dx.doi.org/10.1...
http(s)://doi.org/10.1...
DOI: 11.11111/aaa.111&1111&11

Now I have a regular expression that handles the code just 10.1.... $doiPattern = "/\b(10\.[0-9]{4,}(?:\.[0-9]+)*\/(?:(?![\"&\'])\S)+)\b/";
Unfortunately, my code can't process all the options that I presented. But just pulls out the 10.1... from the full links. https://doi.org/ 11.11111/aaa.111111111
The code I have tried:
$element = "Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem `https://dx.doi.org/11.11111/aaa.111111111` Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem `https://doi.org/11.11111/aaa.111111111` Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem `DOI: 11.11111/aaa.111&1111&11` Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem `DOI:11.11111/aaa.111&1111&11` Lorem Lorem Lorem "

$doiPattern = "/\b(10\.[0-9]{4,}(?:\.[0-9]+)*\/(?:(?![\"&\'])\S)+)\b/";

$doiData = preg_match_all($doiPattern, $element, $doiMatches);

foreach ($doiMatches[0] as $doiMatch) {
       //...
}

how do I update the regular expression so that it takes into account the conditions. For example, a space between the words DOI:, as well as a links?

There are websites that allow you to explore regular expressions in an interactive way, so that you can experiment more productively than with PHP code. In any case, define the different patterns separately and then combine them afterwards.

Sorry if DOI is some well-known standard I'm not aware of, but it'd be useful to know what the format can be like (not the surrounding, but the value you want to exact). In any case, when faced to vastly different possibilities, I'd rather make several passes with simple expressions rather than compiling a single monster regexp.

@ÁlvaroGonzález The format of DOI 11.11111/aaa.111111111 is what I need to work with)

Can you describe the pattern more generally? Does it always start with 10 or 11, or can it be any 2-digit number?

Regex questions with yatta-yatta'ed sample input text Need Clarification.

Here is a working solution with an updated regex pattern and PHP code.
<?php

$string = "Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem https://dx.doi.org/11.11111/aaa.111111111 Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem https://doi.org/11.11111/aaa.111111111 Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem DOI: 11.11111/aaa.111&1111&11 Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem DOI:11.11111/aaa.111&1111&11 Lorem Lorem Lorem";

// Define regex pattern for DOI
$pattern = '/((https?:\/\/(?:dx\.)?doi\.org\/|DOI:\s*)(\d+(\.\d+)*\/\S+))/i';

// Perform the match
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

// Print all matches
print_r($matches[0]);

Output
Array
(
    [0] => https://dx.doi.org/11.11111/aaa.111111111
    [1] => https://doi.org/11.11111/aaa.111111111
    [2] => DOI: 11.11111/aaa.111&1111&11
    [3] => DOI:11.11111/aaa.111&1111&11
)

Explanation of the Regex Pattern Used Above

Protocol Matching:
https?:\/\/: This part checks for a URL starting with either http:// or https://.

Domain and Path:
(?:dx\.)?doi\.org\/: This section matches the domain doi.org optionally preceded by dx..

OR Operator:
|: This symbol means "or". It's like saying "match either this part or that part".

DOI Identifier:
DOI:\s*: This part matches the literal string DOI: followed by optional whitespace characters.

DOI Value:
\d+(\.\d+)*\/\S+: This part captures the actual DOI value:
\d+: Matches one or more digits.
(\.\d+)*: Allows for zero or more occurrences of a dot followed by one or more digits. This is for version numbers.
\/: Matches a forward slash.
\S+: Matches one or more non-whitespace characters, which typically represent the remainder of the DOI.

Case Insensitivity:
/i: This flag makes the pattern case-insensitive, so it matches both uppercase and lowercase letters.


